# Access Denied for ListObjects AWS STS and S3 Client

Tags: php, amazon-s3, http-status-code-403, aws-sts

I am unable to use the method ListObjects to access AWS S3 using the Secure Token Service.

The documentation states a bucket and it's object can be private, while we can use AWS STS to gain temporary credentials to access the S3 objects.

I am attempting to create a Graphics Server. I have a separate service that you can query. During the response, my plan is to use AWS STS to expose the images in my S3 bucket.

```
use Aws\Sts\StsClient;
use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;

$bucket = 'bucket_name';


// the security credentials that you use to obtain temporary security credentials.
$stsClient = StsClient::factory(array(
    'credentials' => array(
        'secret'    => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        'key' => 'YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY'
    ),
    'region'=>'us-east-1',
    'version'=>'latest'
));




// Fetch the federated credentials.
$sessionToken = $stsClient->getFederationToken([
    'Name'              => 'IAM-Username',
    'DurationSeconds'    => '3600',
    'PolicyName'         => 'my-policy'
]);

// The following will be part of your less trusted code. You provide temporary
// security credentials so the code can send authenticated requests to Amazon S3.

$s3 = new S3Client([
    'region' => 'us-east-1',
    'version' => 'latest',
    'credentials' => [
        'key'    => $sessionToken['Credentials']['AccessKeyId'],
        'secret' => $sessionToken['Credentials']['SecretAccessKey'],
        'token'  => $sessionToken['Credentials']['SessionToken']
    ]
]);
print_r($sessionToken);
echo "<br/>";
echo "<br/>";
try {
    $result = $s3->listObjects([
        'Bucket' => $bucket
    ]);
} catch (S3Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
}
```

I was expecting a list of S3 Object Keys. But instead I get an error message:

> Error executing "ListObjects" on "https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket_name?encoding-type=url"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `GET 
>   https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket_name?encoding-type=url` resulted in a `403 >Forbidden` response: AccessDeniedAccess Denied AccessDenied (client): >Access Denied - AccessDeniedAccess Denied  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Answer (score 0):

found my answer. I was calling the wrong method.

I changed this:

```
$sessionToken = $stsClient->getFederationToken([
    'Name'              => 'IAM-Username',
    'DurationSeconds'    => '3600',
    'PolicyName'         => 'my-policy'
]);
```

to this:

```
$sessionToken = $stsClient->getSessionToken([
    'Name'              => 'IAM-Username',
    'DurationSeconds'    => '3600',
    'PolicyName'         => 'my-policy'
]);
```

use getSessionToken instead of getFederationToken, which is kinda obvious.